# ereg_replace vs preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<?php
$string = '\n \n \n \n';
$patterns = '/\n/';
$replacements = '/\\n/';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

This segment of code does not seem to work, Any suggestions on why this is happening. It does not echo anything at all. I can get it working with ereg but wanted to change over to preg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issues here...

- Are you trying to create a string made of new-line characters? `'\n \n \n \n'` is not the way, it does not works. Use `"\n \n \n \n"` and read the PHP official manual about strings **[here](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)**.
- Your pattern is not escaped correctly. Try `'/\\n/'`, anyway I'm not sure your version does not work.
- What's the reason for your `'/\\n/'` replacement? **Please provide an example of input string and desired output.**

If you are trying to escape strings to save them in a database, you are **completely on the wrong way**. Google for *php database escaping*, and read about **[`mysql_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)** (or equivalent ones if you are not using MySQL). There are functions to do it, and you **have to** use them. You cannot rely (or there is no reason to do it) on custom made functions using regular expressions.

Comment: I am trying to escape user input, so if they type in \n when it is updated in the database its not just \n but \\n instead.

Comment: @Mintuz Ok, so you are **completely on the wrong way**. I edit my answer, accept it if I'm right about your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Docs: `ereg has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Anyways, your $patterns isn't escaped properly. You need four `\`'s - see below:

```
<?php
$string = '\n \n \n \n';
$patterns = '/\\\\n/';
$replacements = '/\\n/';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string); // string(19) "/\n/ /\n/ /\n/ /\n/"
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean for `\n` to be a new line character, you may not use single quotes ('), use double quotes (") instead